# MDX: Using named set in aggregate (last 7 days)

Tags: time, mdx

I have built a DataCalculation dimension that should have a time based calculated. It should sum for each measure the last 7 day, parallel period etc. 
I have built a named set for last 7 days:

```
CREATE  SET CURRENTCUBE.[Last 7 days]
AS {
StrToMember(Cstr("[Dmn_Dates].[date calc].&["+
Cstr(Format(Now(),"yyyy-MM-dd")) +"T00:00:00]"))
:
StrToMember(Cstr("[Dmn_Dates].[Date calc].&["+
Cstr(Format(Now()-7,"yyyy-MM-dd")) +"T00:00:00]"))
};
```

And then tried to use it on a calculated member: 
create member currentcube.[Dmn_ DateTool].[Date Tool].[Last 7 Days_]
as

```
aggregate(
{
StrToMember(Cstr("[Dmn_Dates].[date calc].&["+
Cstr(Format(Now(),"yyyy-MM-dd")) +"T00:00:00]"))
:
StrToMember(Cstr("[Dmn_Dates].[Date calc].&["+
Cstr(Format(Now()-7,"yyyy-MM-dd")) +"T00:00:00]"))
}
,([Dmn_ DateTool].[Date Tool].[regular],measures.LeadCounter))
, visible = 1;
```

It doesn't work. What I get is a calculated memeber [Last 7 days] that show the same value as the regular value.

Thanks reading until here.

Answer (score 1):

I would check the generated set validity and that it contains the right members; sth like:

```
select [Last 7 days] on 0 ...
```

Perhaps you've to reverse the from/to : Now() - 7 : Now instead of Now() : Now() - 7 ...

Answer (score 1):

When you use the [Range operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146001.aspx) in an expression like member1: member2, member1 must come before member2 in hierarchical order. Otherwise the range operator will return an empty set.

Moreover you have to be sure that your expressions like `StrToMember(Cstr("[Dmn_Dates].[date calc].&["+Cstr(Format(Now(),"yyyy-MM-dd")) +"T00:00:00]"))` really returns an existing member:  **null:null** returns the empty set.